# Related form fields next to each other

Tags: usability, forms, formatting

It seems the best practise when it comes to forms is to lay the fields out in a [one column layout](https://uxdesign.cc/design-better-forms-96fadca0f49c) - should this be true for fields that are related to each other?

For example, would a suitable exception to this be First name / last name and date of birth? As they are commonly expressed on a single line, e.g:

```
[First name] [Last name]
[Gender]
[Job title]
[E-mail]
[DOB - Day][DOB - Month][DOB - Year]
```

Or would it still be optimal to do:

```
[First name]
[Last name]
[Gender]
[Job title]
[E-mail]
[DOB - Day]
[DOB - Month]
[DOB - Year]
```

And is there any research behind which ever is best?

Answer (score 4):

First, I agree with you on the single column layout since the Mobile First Approach helps in many ways  [**[Why Should I Design for Mobile First]**](http://www.webinsation.com/why-should-i-design-for-mobile-first/).

> On grouping related fields horizontally I think it will be a matter
>   of:
>
> - Affordance
> - Consistent user experience across devices

## Examples:

[image]

---

[image]

**For Small Screens:**

[image]

---

The fields you mentioned above *Firstname and Lastname* can become **Fullname**. And DOB can be a **single field** with [supportive html5 patterns](https://www.wufoo.com/html5/types/4-date.html) and placeholders.

Comment: Up-voted for points about combining Name fields into Full name (unfortunately, my form is for searching a database where names are split so I can't apply it). For Date of birth, GDS has found that using separate text fields (with `type=number`) has been most successful - https://designnotes.blog.gov.uk/2013/12/05/asking-for-a-date-of-birth/